# How to set an OnClickListener for ListView variants?

Tags: java, android

I succesfully added an item in the ListView, but I do want to add a ClickListener for it to go to another scene/layout.

```
List<String> objectives = new ArrayList<String>();
if (getSharedPreferences("objectives", MODE_PRIVATE).getString("objective1", null) != null){
    objectives.add(getSharedPreferences("objectives", MODE_PRIVATE).getString("objective1", ""));
}
ArrayAdapter<String> listInput = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
    this,
    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
    objectives
);
objectiveList.setAdapter(listInput);
```

I want to add the ClickListener on a condition (if), for the item's name too. Please help me. :)

Comment: Please see: [How do I avoid misusing tags?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354427/how-do-i-avoid-misusing-tags)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a [OnItemClickListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemClickListener) on the list that do something only when the item's name matches what you want.

```
List<String> matchList = new ArrayList<String>( 
            Arrays.asList("name1", 
                          "name2", 
                          "name3")); 

objectiveList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        String name = objectives.get(position);
        if (matchList.contains(name) {
            // DO STUFF
        }
    }
});
```

Best